# Live HTML editor for client

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a website / webapp for a client, and they aren't really techy, if I may.
WHat I'm going to create is a very simple inline HTML editor for them, so they can change their own content on their site w/o having me do it for them in the future.

What I need, is text formatting and the logic to create and properly use the basic HTML tags like: a, img, h1-h6, p, and some custom div's that I use to get some special header types and whatnot.

What I'd like to ask though, is: what do you think is the fastest/easiest way I can achieve a usable result for this task?

I know I need to be able to open the html file in question for edit, and when they click "save", it needs to write the changes to that same file. Not only that, but I somehow need to be able to "hide" all the advanced code that is in the HTML (or in this case, it's PHP files) like javascript and PHP code.

Any help or pointers to a good method would be greatly appreciated. I have time constraints, so the editor should not be too complex or advanced. Just be able to provide the necessary tools to add in text/images/links and formatting options.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you need to be using templates. Look into something like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).  Along with a rich-text editor, you should be able to accomplish your goal.

Comment: many editors are available. you can use one of them. and Smarty would also help for templating as suggested by Ayman Safadi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at:

```
http://www.tinymce.com/
```

It provides a customisable WYSIWYG.  You can switch on or off whatever functions you need.

Comment: This does look like something I need, indeed. If you are already familiar with it, will this change the file on the server after edit? Also, the site is already finished, but he wanted these edits after that, so it's not using any templating system. I just didnt figure javscipt based editors could connect to the server in that way.

Comment: JS Editors can't connect to the server.  You will need to implement the server side functionality separately for updating the page content.  The tinymce editor will allow you to put an easy to use editor as your frontend.

Comment: Yeah I found some info on it. Thank you, I'll hopefully get it working! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another very powerfull and poular WYSIWYG customisable editor is [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)